# If Commercial Realtor refers Tenant to a Landlord, then Tenant breaches Tenancy Agreement, can Commercial Realtor be liable to Landlord?

Tags: hong-kong, business-lease

[This is my case.](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/142165)
Are there legal reasons that Shopping Centre Landlord (NWD in my case) alleges that a vacancy is unavailable to me, but let Commercial Realtors (CBRE in my case) lease THE SAME VACANCY to me? Possible that Landlord contracted away some of Landlord's liability to CBRE? Then Landlord will want CBRE to lease vacancy — and not lease directly to me —  because CBRE can reduce  Landlord's liability.

I know that if CBRE introduces a Tenant that gets into legal issues, CBRE can lose face, reputation in Landlord's eyes.  Landlord will loathe, lose confidence in CBRE. But CBRE can't sue Landlord just because CBRE loses reputation???

Tenant can breach Tenancy Agreement  by  pay rent late, arrear, go bankrupt, skip rent and disappear!

Comment: Your linked question on PF&M-SE states you have a solicitor. Have you asked them? And I think your answer lies in the very clear comments made to that post.

Comment: @RockApe I don't want to ask my EXPENSIVE solicitor, because solicitor charges me every 6 minutes. Solicitor will charge me if I ask them this. If answers here are good enough, I don't need to pay solicitor to ask them this.

Comment: I would highly recommend to make this question conform more to the Stack Exchange standards (don't use ALL CAPS, don't put more than one question mark at the end of a single sentence, etc.). Hopefully the answer you received is good enough for you. I disagree with the others that you need to ask your lawyer who is charging you every 6 months ... if everyone had to do that, we would not have a Law.SE site. But you've got 4 close votes and if you don't polish your question, it will most likely get closed. I will probably cast the only "leave open" vote since I don't see this as off-topic.

Comment: Linked page is 404 - Page not found. This is dangerously close to requesting specific legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there legal reasons that Shopping Centre Landlord (NWD in my case) alleges that a vacancy is unavailable to me, but let Commercial Realtors (CBRE in my case) lease THE SAME VACANCY to me?

Most likely there are. For instance, some contract between NWD and the commercial realtor might prevent the former from offering to others some specific set of premises. If so, leasing any of those premises directly to you would put NWD in breach of contract with respect to the commercial realtor.

Even if there is no such contract between NWD and the commercial realtor, NWD's intentional misrepresentation that Shop 23 is unavailable does not seem to be actionable. Generally speaking, it is within NWD's freedom of contract to decline leasing its premise(s) regardless of whether it causes you a loss: There is nothing in your description suggesting that NWD might be incurring unlawful discrimination. Therefore, the *falsity* of the reason(s) for not leasing to you the premise has no legal effect on anyone.

Comment: Thank you!!! I just read your profile. I was wondering if you are lawyer. So sorry about your cases! So many people think Hong Kong lawyers are TOO expensive and Hong Kong judges bad. But who knew USA is just as bad????

Comment: @Michelle Thank you kindly. I am not a lawyer, have never aspired to become one, and would never recommend it as a career. Although honest judges exist, corruption of the judiciary is a worldwide issue. Knowing about the law is as important as the awareness that many, many judges are driven by interests other than --and oftentimes contrary to-- the interests of *justice*.